# keeping track of indices in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
limits = [0.09090909,0.18181818,0.27272727]
res = [0.001,0.002,0.0923,0.0978,0.19374,0.21838]
```

limits list specifies the range and what I want to see how many values in **res** are less than for example the first value in limits and so on. And in a different list I want to store the last index of res whose value is less that 0.09, last index of res whose value is less than 0.1818 and so on. 
So the result would be:

track = [1,3,5]

But my code is not doing that. My code so far is:

```
index = 0 ##this variable keeps track of where we are in limits list.
counter = 0 ## keeps track of indices in res list
for each_position in res:
    if each_position <= limits[index]:
        counter += 1
    else:
        track.append(counter)
        index += 1
```

What I get from this code is [2,3] whereas the output should be [1,3,5].
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your loop a bit. Instead of looping through the results first, loop through the limits. Then for each limit check the results. Whenever you encounter a value in `res` larger than a limit, append the previous index in `track` list, break out of the inner loop and continue for remaining limits.

```py
for limit in limits:
    for index, value in enumerate(res):
        if value > limit:
            track.append(index - 1)
            break
        if len(res)-1 == index:
            track.append(index)
```

Edit: my apologies. If you do not find a value in `res` that is larger than a limit, then store the last index of `res`.

Comment: but this gives me [1,3] and misses the last index.

Comment: @Peter i've edited my answer. Check it and let me know.